# Blocked port - no process

Tags: linux, port

Working on a Linux Debian machine.
When trying to start Tomcat7 a warning about port 80 being block is thrown. Furthermore, the deployed webapps cannot be accessed (404 error).

Tried to figure out what process is keeping port 80 busy with `netstat -lantp | grep ':80'` and this is the result:

```
tcp6    0      0 :::80            :::*              LISTEN      -
```

And this is where my Linux knowledge ended. Is it safe to assume that something is listening to `:80` or not? (considering that the PID is displayed as `-`).

Any idea of how should I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is indeed listening. When you run `netstat -lantp | grep ':80'` as root it will show a PID.